# computational complexity of convolution

Tags: complexity-theory, fft, convolution

I read that the computational complexity of the general convolution algorithm is `O(n^2)`, while by means of the FFT is `O(n log n)`.

What about convolution in 2-D and 3-D?

Any reference?

Comment: what is n? The input?

Answer (score 14):

As for two- and three-dimensional convolution and Fast Fourier Transform the complexity is following:

```
                            2D                     3D
```

---

```
Convolution               O(n^4)                  O(n^6)
```

---

```
FFT                   O(n^2 log^2 n)           O(n^3 log^3 n)
```

Reference: [Slides on Digital Image Processing](https://is.muni.cz/auth/el/1433/podzim2011/PV131/um/8943284/lecture04_2008.pdf), slide no. 34.

Comment: Broken link. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: Did you get any functional link after all? For 1D?

Comment: what is n? The input?

Comment: @user3352632 - input is an `n` by `n` matrix.

Comment: If input is n^x multidimensional cube, is it correct then that generally the complexeties are still O(n^2) and O(n log n), where n is the volume of the multidimensional object? Or is it O(n log^d n) for FFT, where n is the volume and d is the dimensionality?