# How can I improve this algorithm ? (Image Processing)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Ok, so after some hours of documentation on Image Processing topic (I'm a beginner programmer) I decide I want to implement a edge detection function of my own to better understand the mathematics behind it. I was able to do it fortunately, but my algorithm it's just way too slow(O(n^2)). I'll post the code with the part of frame processing below:

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
grayed  = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
rows, cols = grayed.shape
for row in range(rows-2):
    for col in range(cols-2):
        Gx = grayed.item(row+2,col)+2*grayed.item(row+2,col+1)+grayed.item(row+2,col+1)-(grayed.item(row,col)+2*grayed.item(row,col+1)+grayed.item(row,col+2))
        Gy = grayed.item(row,col+2)+2*grayed.item(row+1,col+2)+grayed.item(row+2,col+1)-(grayed.item(row,col)+2*grayed.item(row+1,col)+grayed.item(row+2,col))
        grad = math.sqrt(Gx**2 + Gy**2)
        grayed.itemset((row, col), grad)
cv2.imshow('frame', grayed)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I am not a python expert, but I would start to use a ndarray from bumpy, it should accelerate the process.

Comment: Could you give more info as to what kind of data you are passing to this function? Maybe post a small example. I believe that you could greatly speed this up using either numpy or a combination of numpy and Cython. Using Cython will get you close to C speeds. This of course will only change the run time of the algorithm but it will still be O(n^2).

Comment: I've edited my post. I began using the grayscaled image instead of the untouched frame and it did speed up a little bit my process. Also I've deleted the kernel creation since it was not useful at all. Problem is that it's still not fast enough.

Comment: I think it more related to code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Have you read their [on-topic help centre?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyzed your code:

you're applying two gradient filters, one for direction `x`, one for `y`.

these filters look like:

```
-1 -2 -1
 0  0  0
 1  3  0
```

and

```
-1 0 1
-2 0 2
-1 1 0
```

I guess these are typos (?) and you rather wanted to have these:

`Gx`:

```
-1 -2 -1
 0  0  0
 1  2  1
```

and for `Gy`

```
-1 0 1
-2 0 2
-1 0 1
```

This filtering process is also known as `convolution`. In fact, you've got a runtime of `O(4)` since the kernel is 2d, too. There're many ressources on the web, on this, for instance [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16510775/1150303)

You can indeed improve the theoretical runtime by making use of the concept of [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution). For instance, if using the FFT, the runtime can be brought down to `O(n^2*log^2(n))`.

However, much more perfomance increase you'd obtain by using filter methods of [scipy - `convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.convolve) or [opencv - `filter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d).
They will have a very good runtime, plus possibly even more important, they're implemented in C and won't slow down as dramatically as when using python loops.